# New code not showing up in sonarqube code coverage measures

Tags: sonarqube

New code (I've checked and it's definitely new) doesn't always show up under code coverage measures.

I see no link saying 'On New Code X.Y%'

Interestingly, I do get an 'On New Code X.Y%' link in the maintainability rating.

Is there a good reason for this?  If it's a bug, it's happening on other projects too, and seems to occur quite commonly.

I'm running Sonarqube 5.6.5

Comment: do you use an SCM plugin (ex: Git Plugin)? have you set a value for the leak period? If yes, what it is?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen in SonarQube - *an error out of control :)*. Re-checkout project folder and re-try or else re-create the project. Faced this earlier.